# After Facebook login gives exception but in login with registration form it works good in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I have two signup option with one option i got perfectly home page but if i login with Facebook than it comes next view controller perfectly but after that if i click any button of home page menu it gives exception .

> 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'"
>        if i login with my registered user which i register from my side then it works good.

```
- (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:(NSError *)error
{
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                                  parameters:@{ @"fields": @"id,name,picture,email,gender"}
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        // Insert your code here
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary* json = result;

            NSLog(@"email id is %@",[json valueForKey:@"email"]);
            NSLog(@"json is %@",json);

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[json valueForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"fbemail"];

            name =[json objectForKey:@"name"];
            email =[json objectForKey:@"email"];
            gender=[json objectForKey:@"gender"];
            NSLog(@"name is %@",name);

            NSLog(@"emailp is %@",email);
            NSLog(@"gender is %@",gender);
            NSDictionary *pictureData  = [result valueForKey:@"picture"];
            NSDictionary *redata = [pictureData valueForKey:@"data"];
            _urlpicture = [redata valueForKey:@"url"];

            HomeViewController *pushWithSlot=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

            pushWithSlot.geturl=_urlpicture;
            pushWithSlot.getname=name;
            pushWithSlot.getemail=email;
            pushWithSlot.getgender=gender;



            [self presentViewController:pushWithSlot  animated:YES
                             completion:nil];
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: the meaning is your Homeviewcontroller does not incluede in UInavgitaion controller

Comment: Have you tried with [self.navigation pushViewController:pushWithSlot animated:YES]; ?

It would be safer to store you user data in some object,  and do the push on the main thread out of the didCompleteWithResult method - When you go back to your first viewController for example ( I suppose it has a navigation controller. ). The facebook login controller must be presented outside of the navigation controller chain.

Comment: But i don't need to go back previous view ..thats why i use present view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select your `LoginViewController` and  goto XCode Menu --> **Editor**--> **Embed In** --> **Navigation Controller.**

the above function is not work

1. add your `HomeViewController` onto the existing navigation controller's stack instead of presenting it modally OR

   2. You need to embed your `HomeViewController` in another navigation controller and then create and present that navigation controller modally from your loginViewController

another way, `HomeViewController` needs to be embedded in a navigation controller before you can use Push Segues from it

Comment: ..yaa sir i am waiting your reply...But i already select my navigation controller in login....I easily login and perfect work when i login with my self register view controller

Comment: are you added the **HomeViewController** in inside the navigation controller stack

Comment: i already add navigation controller in login and home..I think we should covert to chat.

Comment: can you send your code to my mail Id karthik.saral@gmail.com, I will check and tell the answer

Comment: @harshchauhan -- would u need a nay additional help or your problem is solved

Comment: if i use HomeViewController *pushWithSlot=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
                     
                     [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[pushWithSlot] animated:YES]; Then it works fine but no value go to next view

Comment: set viewcontroller is used for apply the set not the navigate, if you navigate the datawiill apply , got it my bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94414/discussion-between-harsh-chauhan-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: bro send the whole project then how do I check

Comment: create a drop box or sendspace link and sent the link to me bro

Comment: if my answer is hopeful give the upvote else tell me what the help u need